# Collectionview inside Tableview - image not appearing in collection view

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am trying to display a collection view of images in a tableview. However, the image does not appear. The collection view and tableview cell are loaded; it's just the image not appearing.

Tableview Cell - this is tableview in the viewcontroller

```
  import UIKit

  struct Wolves {
  var name: String?
  var imageUrl: NSString?
 }

 class WTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {


var Count: [Wolves] = []


   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return Count.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.row)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.loadImageWith(imgView: cell.wImageView, url: Count[indexPath.row].imageUrl as String?)
    cell.wImageView.applyCircularImageView()
    collectionView.reloadData()
    return cell
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
       return CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
   }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 10
}



override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    CollectionView.delegate = self
    CollectionView.dataSource = self
    Count.append(Wolves(name: "1", imageUrl: "example.jpg"))
    CollectionView.reloadData()
    self.CollectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
    
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@IBOutlet weak var CollectionView: UICollectionView!


  }
```

Collectionview Cell

```
import UIKit

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var wImageView: UIImageView!
override class func awakeFromNib() {
}
```

}

View Controller

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath:     IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell : TableViewCell = TableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "wTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! wTableViewCell
        return cell
}
```

Comment: Show all relevant lines of code for your table guy.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to set the imageView Height constraint ?

Comment: Try to give height to UIViewImage from storyboard

Comment: I assume loadImagesWith is asynchronous. That means the cell image view may not be available fast enough to be displayed. You have to save images in a local array inside view controller to not get from url each time.